# Docker run image with wrong architecture on raspberry pi

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi

js server in docker. On my Windows 10 64bit it works fine. But when i try to run the image on my raspberry pi: `standard_init_linux.go:190: exec user process caused "exec format error".`

mariu5 in the docker Forum has a workaround. But I do not know what to do with it.
https://forums.docker.com/t/standard-init-linux-go-190-exec-user-process-caused-exec-format-error/49368/4

**Where can I updated the deployment.template.json file and has the Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+ a arm32 architecture?**

Answer (score 0):

You need to rebuild your image on the raspberry pi or find one that is compatible with it.

Perhaps this example might help:
https://github.com/hypriot/rpi-node-example-hello-world

The link you posted is not a work around but rather a "one can't do that".

> You have to run the docker image that was built for a particular
>   Architecture on a docker node that is running that same Architecture.
>
> Take docker out of the picture for a moment. You can’t run a Linux
>   application compiled and built on a Linux ARM machine and run it on a
>   Linux amd64 machine. You can’t run a Linux application compiled and
>   built on a Linux Power machine on a Linux amd64 machine.

- https://forums.docker.com/t/standard-init-linux-go-190-exec-user-process-caused-exec-format-error/49368/4

Comment: Ok... I'll try it. Build once, Run anywhere... Was not that the motto of Docker? Is not it possible to build an image for a different architecture? On Win for Pie?

Comment: "build once run anywhere" was the motto when docker only supported x86 arch but that has changed and i guess so should the motto.  

Seams like docker is moving to support arm support on x86: 
https://techcrunch.com/2019/04/24/docker-partners-with-arm/

Though currently i think it might just be easier just to build the image on your pi. 

Perhaps you can get this to work:
https://ownyourbits.com/2018/06/27/running-and-building-arm-docker-containers-in-x86/